# enum.valueOf(String name) missing from Javadoc 1.5 and 1.6

Tags: java, enums, javadoc

This is probably a stupid question, but I'm using the method `enum.valueOf(String name)`. No problem there, except that when I was checking the javadoc to find out more about this method, I couldn't find it. There is javadoc for `valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name)` but none for  `enum.valueOf(String name)` (which would suggest that a method with this signature doesn't exist - but clearly it does).

Am I missing something here, or is this an oversight in the javadoc for the API?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no method Enum.valueOf(String)  However, every `enum` has a `values()` and `valueOf(String)` method generated by the compiler and these are documented.  They are static methods and thus cannot be overridden or defined in a super class or interface.

```
Enum e = Enum.valueOf(""); // this doesn't compile
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#values%28%29

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html#values%28%29

Its the same in Java 5.0, 6 or 7.

For Java 5.0 [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.9 (archive.org copy)](http://web.archive.org/web/20130425211659/http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.9) (search for values)
For Java 7 http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2 provided by @kapep

Comment: @kapep Thank you for the reference. I could not find one for Java 5.0

Comment: BTW - when I wrote enum.valueOf(String name), I was using "enum" as a shortcut for an actual enum. In this concrete case, the enum was the class SourceMedia (from an excercise in "Harnessing Hibernate.") It still seems odd to me that this method doesn't show up in the javadoc for Enum.

Comment: And - THANKS! (that was my first comment, but it got lost ;-}

Comment: They are not in Enum because Enum doesn't have these methods and no simple way to document them.  It could be added to the class description.

Answer (score 10):

Under the hood, `enum.valueOf(String name)` is actually calling [`Enum.valueOf(Class<T> enumType, String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29)